# how to concatenate the names selected in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, formula

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to use a formula to concatenate the name that has been selected in the checkbox by using the delimiter "+". The expected output is highlighted in yellow in the screenshot above. Ideally the formula can be an `ARRAYFORMULA` in cell `F5` instead of making entire column F full of formula. Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps

```
=ArrayFormula(substitute(trim(transpose(query(transpose(if(B5:E, B4:E4,)),,9^9))), " ", " + "))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(IF(B5:B,B4,)&CHAR(10)&IF(C5:C,C4,)&CHAR(10)&IF(D5:D,D4,)&CHAR(10)&IF(E5:E,E4,)),CHAR(10)," + ")
```

This is a fairly simple way to do it that may be easier to understand than a query smush.  The extra CHAR(10)'s [carriage returns] get chopped off the ends and de-duplicated in the middle by the TRIM().  Then the remaining ones are replaced with " + ".

Answer (score 0):

Not an arrayformula but in my opinion a simpler formula to use in each row:
`=TEXTJOIN(" + ",true,arrayformula(if(B3:E3,$B$2:$E$2,"")))`